# Ограничение числа ядер приложению

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли ограничить число используемых ядер процессора для программы? Т.е. вместо 8 использовать 4. Или это всё на уровне системы?

Answer (score 2):

Можно, но только на уровне JVM, то есть надо запускать виртуальную Java машину, в которой будет исполняться программа с флагом, например:

```
-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=4
```

Доступно начиная с JDK 8, [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Comment: А это действует на реальном устройстве?

Comment: Конечно, JVM работает поверх реального устройства. По умолчанию при запуске JVM берет у реального устройства количество процессоров, но это можно изменить

Comment: Спасибо! Будем пробовать